# How to initiate value for dlmModPoly?

Tags: r, time-series, kalman-filter, dlm

I'm trying to build a model to predict a product's sale price. I'm researching the dlm package. Looks like I should use dlmModPoly, dlmMLE, dlmFilter, dlmSmooth, and finally dlmForecast. I'm looking at the Nile River example and I have a few questions:

1. If I only want to predict future sale price based on observed sale price, I should use a univariate model, correct?
2. how do I initiate value for dV and dW?
   In the example code: 
   dlmModPoly(1, dV = exp(par[1]), dW = exp(par[2]))
   Why dV and dW was initiated that way?
3. I'm not sure how to read output of dlmForecast. 
   f is matrix of expected values of future observations. new Obs is list of matrices containing the simulated future values of the observations.
   Should I take f as the forecast result? Or new Obs?
4. In my experiment, f (output from dlmForecast) has all 0s. And I have huge variance like 10016568. Does that mean my result is not valid?

Thanks a lot for any insights!

Comment: There may be an underlying statistical question (understanding Kalman filters  / dynamic linear models) but this seems too focused on a particular R package

Answer (score 2):

I know this answer is late but it might still be of help to others who find this.

1. Yes, exactly.
2. `par` seems to be a variable that stores two parameters of the model. These parameters will later be estimated. The `exp()` specification rules out negative numbers and might improve MLE with very small numbers.
3. As you said it. `f` contains expected values, whereas `newObs` has simulated observations. Refer to the [manual](http://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dlm/dlm.pdf&ei=XNjGUsruOufa4ATiwoCgBg&usg=AFQjCNFYLDWdu-ovdTRGkvpYxb_d55x9QQ&sig2=vOur2nTthW0qkSgHXwAI2Q&bvm=bv.58187178,d.bGE) for further details.
4. Please post the entire code of your analysis, otherwise it is difficult to say what might have gone wrong.

**Generally**, I recommend the very good [introductory paper](http://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CEUQFjAC&url=http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dlm/vignettes/dlm.pdf&ei=VdjGUtGpKqSa4wTEyIFg&usg=AFQjCNGhCgam4R9ugKpSUU4nluM02yZ22Q&sig2=yN42spDNHBR5iB9BhrNiEw&bvm=bv.58187178,d.bGE) by the package Author Giovanni Petris. It explains how to use the various functions in an analysis.